# Tensorflow - Correct way to read data from single large txt file

Tags: tensorflow

I want to ask what the correct pattern to read large text data in batches using tensorflow?

Here is one line of text data. There are billions of lines of such data in single txt file.

`target context label`

Right now I am trying to use tfrecords as recommended in official documentation.

here is my way

```
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([self._train_data], num_epochs=self._num_epochs)

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
        features={
            'target': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'context': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        })

    target = features['target']
    context = features['context']
    label = features['label']
    min_after_dequeue = 10000
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * self._batch_size
    target_batch, context_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [target, context, label], batch_size=self._batch_size, capacity=capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue, num_threads=self._concurrent_steps)
```

After that I used timeline to do profiling. The result shows that this part take most of the time.
Here is the profiling diagram.
[the profiling result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwIpq.png)

Btw. I am using batch size 500.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your CPU fully loaded? If not, it's possible that you need to use more threads (in the `num_threads` argument to `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`) to parse records from the file. Other possibilities: you could use `reader.read_up_to(n)`, `tf.parse_example()` rather than `tf.parse_single_example()`, and pass `enqueue_many=True` to `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` in order perform batch parsing, which should be more efficient.

Comment: @mrry that's it I use `reader.read_up_to(n)`,`tf.parse_example()` to read multiple lines per time and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It is often more efficient to apply [`tf.parse_example()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_example) to a batch of elements than to apply [`tf.parse_single_example()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_single_example) on each individual element, because the former op has an efficient multithreaded implementation that can be used when the input contains multiple examples. The following rewrite of your code should improve the performance:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([self._train_data], num_epochs=self._num_epochs)

reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

# Read a batch of up to 128 examples at once.
_, serialized_examples = reader.read_up_to(filename_queue, 128)

features = tf.parse_example(
    serialized_examples,
    # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
    features={
        'target': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'context': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    })

target = features['target']
context = features['context']
label = features['label']
min_after_dequeue = 10000
capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * self._batch_size

# Pass `enqueue_many=True` because the input is now a batch of parsed examples.
target_batch, context_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [target, context, label], batch_size=self._batch_size, capacity=capacity,
    min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue, num_threads=self._concurrent_steps,
    enqueue_many=True)
```